# Как выписать строки из одной таблицы в другую по ключу?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Первая вкладка:

```
А     B     C
кл    4     6
цук   3     5
кл    3     55
цук   6     5
```

Нужно выписать в соседнюю вкладку те строки, где в А столбце написано кл. То есть:

```
А     B     C
кл    4     6
кл    3     55
```

Как будто какой-то массив использовать или типа того..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покажу для *Excel*, перевести функции не проблема.

Слева от исходной таблицы в столбце *А* пишем доп. формулу:

```
=ЕСЛИ(B2=$F$2;МАКС($A$1:A1)+1)
=If(B2=$F$2;MAX($A$1:A1)+1)
```

в *F2* - ключ.

Формула для таблицы-результата:

```
=ЕСЛИ(СТРОКА(B1)>МАКС('sht1'!$A$2:$A$5);"";ВПР(СТРОКА(B1);'sht1'!$A$2:$D$5;СТОЛБЕЦ(C1);0))
=If(ROW(B1)>MAX('sht1'!$A$2:$A$5);"";VLOOKUP(ROW(B1);'sht1'!$A$2:$D$5;COLUMN(C1);0))
```

Чтобы не считать в каждой формуле, *MAX('sht1'!$A$2:$A$5)* можно вывести в отдельную ячейку.

Если нужен и столбец с ключом - заменить *COLUMN(C1)* на *COLUMN(B1)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если без доп. столбца, то простой формулой не получится, нужно применить формулу массива. В *Excel* такая формула вводится сочетанием *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*, в Google -таблицах фрмула начинается с *=FormulaArray*

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ИНДЕКС(C$2:C$5;НАИМЕНЬШИЙ(ЕСЛИ($B$2:$B$5=$F$2;СТРОКА($B$2:$B$5)-1);СТРОКА(A1)));0)
=IFERROR(INDEX(C$2:C$5;SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$5=$F$2;ROW($B$2:$B$5)-1);ROW(A1)));0)
```

Сомнения: а есть ли *Google* -таблицах *IFERROR*?

Comment: Интересное решение. Конечно, накладывает некоторую громоздкость в виде технического столбца, но в целом рабочее.

Comment: Последнее решение в ответе - без доп. столбца, но формула массива тяжелее в вычислениях и очень часто вариант с доп. столбцом выгоднее. Если ни одно, ни другое - макрос писать надо.

Comment: Хм. Ну тогда у вас какая-то не рабочая формула выходит. Он будет находить наименьшее значение между всеми номерами строк, подходящих условию, а значит всегда давать один ответ (первое вхождение)

Comment: Проверьте... *НАИМЕНЬШИЙ(массив;строка)* Про протягивании вниз номер строки меняется. И не забудьте - формула массива.

Comment: Ну так вот предположим результат `IF($B$2:$B$5=$F$2;ROW($B$2:$B$5)-1)` будет 1 и 3; то есть среди них ищем наименьший. Среди них, а так же номера строки `ROW(A1)` пусть он меняется до 7. Наименьшим всегда будет оставаться единица.

Comment: Нет. Этот фрагмент формирует массив. Для ключа "кл" в данном примере это будет *{1:ЛОЖЬ:3:ЛОЖЬ}*. При протягивании по строкам : *НАИМЕНЬШИЙ(массив;1), НАИМЕНЬШИЙ(массив;2)*...

Comment: Ну так я так и сказал 1 и 3 (проигнорировал ЛОЖЬ, ок, т.к. все-равно не сравниваем). Вот и выходит, что у нас НАИМЕНЬШИЙ выбирается из чисел 1, 3 и номера строки (который я в примере протянул от 1 до 7). И этих трех чисел всегда младшей будет единица.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь со спракой по функции. НАИМЕНЬШИЙ - это не МИН. Наименьший k массива, но не минимальный! *НАИМЕНЬШИЙ({8:2:5:4};3)=5*

Comment: Да, это многое объяснило, благодарю. Интуитивно "Наименьший" не похож на "N-ый по счёту с конца" =)